# VB.Net freezing when adding 10000+ rows to SQL from list

Tags: sql, json, vb.net, web-services, ado.net

I am running a RESTful API service which gets data from a server as a JSON string. Around 20000 rows are being selected.

```
Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim prodlist As List(Of Product) = js.Deserialize(Of List(Of Product))(JSONreturn)
```

The 20000 rows are populated in the list prodlist. Checked the count and manually verified the list.

I need to insert these rows in a client machine. However, while inserting the rows, it freezes or stops after inserting around 600-700 rows. Below is the code I am using for inserting.

```
For Each item As Product In prodlist
                    Dim SPName As String = "someSPname"
                    With connectionstring

                        .Clear()
                        .Parameters("@itemnumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input, , item.itemnumber
                        .Parameters("@itemtype", SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input, , item.itemtype)
                        .Parameters("@DESCRIPTION", SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input, , item.DESCRIPTION)
                        .Execute(SPName)                                                        

                    End With
                Next
```

No error is thrown. It just freezes after inserting roughly 600-700 rows everytime.

Bulk insert is not an option. How do I resolve this?

UPDATE : Adding connection class. Pretty sure there is no issue with this :

```
    Public Class ConnectionClass


    Public ReadOnly Property ConnectionString() As String
        Get
            Return GetConfiguration()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Parameters(ByVal param_name As String, ByVal type As SqlDbType, ByVal direction As ParameterDirection, Optional param_size As Int32 = Nothing, Optional param_value As Object = Nothing)
            Dim sqlParam As SqlParameter = Nothing
            Try

                sqlParam = New SqlParameter(param_name, type)
                sqlParam.Size = param_size
                sqlParam.Direction = direction
                sqlParam.Value = param_value
                Lstparam.Add(sqlParam)
            Finally
                If sqlParam IsNot Nothing Then
                    sqlParam = Nothing
                End If
            End Try
        End Sub


    Public Sub Execute(ByVal strSpName As String, Optional ByVal Type As CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)

            Try
                sqlcmd = New SqlCommand()
                sqlcmd.Connection = connection
                ''Setting the timeout to 50 mins as setup in the previous application
                sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 3000
                If transaction IsNot Nothing Then
                    sqlcmd.Transaction = transaction
                End If
                sqlcmd.CommandType = Type
                sqlcmd.CommandText = strSpName

                For Each argument As SqlParameter In Lstparam 
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(argument)
                Next
                For introw As Integer = 0 To sqlcmd.Parameters.Count - 1
                    If sqlcmd.Parameters.Item(introw).ParameterName.Contains("Parameter") Then
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Item(introw).ParameterName = String.Empty


  End If
            Next
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub



Public Sub Clear()
        ClearParameters()
        Lstparam.Clear()
    End Sub


Public Sub ClearParameters()
        If Not sqlcmd Is Nothing Then
            Do Until sqlcmd.Parameters.Count = 0
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear()
            Loop
        End If
    End Sub







    Public Function GetConfiguration() As String
        Dim sbConnectionString As New StringBuilder
        With sbConnectionString
            .Append("Data Source=")
            .Append(ServerName)
            .Append(";")
            .Append("Initial Catalog =")
            .Append(DatabaseName)
            .Append(";")
            .Append("User ID =")
            .Append(UserName)
            .Append(";")
            .Append("Password =")
            .Append(UserPassword)
        End With
        Return sbConnectionString.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Function CreateClientConnection() As SqlConnection

        Dim connectionString As String

        Try
            connectionString = GetConfiguration()
            Dim substrings() As String = connectionString.ToUpper.Split(";")
            Dim substrings1() As String = connection.ConnectionString.ToUpper.Split(";")
            If Not (connection.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then

                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString
                connection.Open()
            ElseIf Not (Trim(substrings(0)) = Trim(substrings1(0))) Then


                If connection IsNot Nothing Then
                    connection.Dispose()
                End If
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString
                connection.Open()
            End If
            Return connection
        Catch ex As Exception
            If connection IsNot Nothing Then
                connection.Dispose()
            End If
            Throw ex
        End Try

    End Function


End Class
```

Comment: what is connectionstring?

Comment: @Charlie Its a variable which holds the connection settings to the client Database

Comment: The type of that variable is important. It definitely isn't just a string, otherwise your code wouldn't work. If it's something that is holding open the connection and never committing it, it's possible the lack of commit after 700 queries is part of the problem. If it's opening connections from a connection pool and never closing them, you might be consuming all the available connections in the pool.

Comment: The variable is of a user-defined class. This class has properties which get and set the values of connection-timeout, connection-string of type Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Also opening and closing of the connection is handled there. For every insert connection is opened and closed.

Comment: Since the connection code is nonstandard, it would be helpful to include that in your question.

Comment: I can assure you there is no problem with the connection string. There are various Stored procedures which are being used to insert data into various tables using the same connection string. The only issue arises with inserting this list.

Comment: It is very confusing that you have a variable named connection string that is NOT a connection string but instead a custom class. It would probably be best to use the built in connection and query framework built into .NET.

That said, you should attach your custom connection code so others can try to help you with this.

Comment: Why is bulk insert not an option?  What does _It just freezes_ mean?  Is it the UI that freezes?  If you wait, does it eventually finish?  Besides that, you are never disposing your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` instances.  Each time you go through the loop, you create another one.  You could be exhausting the pool.  Also, look into the `Using...End Using` statements when creating connections and commands.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway because the stored procedure is an insert/update. There are rows already present in the table. If the primary key clashes it will update.